# Gmail sends bulk messages sent by postfix to spam - spf, rDNS are set up (headers inside)

Tags: postfix, spam, gmail

here are the headers of the blocked messages (actual domain replaced with domain.com, ip address with n.n.n.n and gmail account name with person.account):

```
Delivered-To: person.name@gmail.com
Received: by 10.216.89.137 with SMTP id c9cs247685wef;
        Tue, 6 Dec 2011 16:06:37 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.224.199.134 with SMTP id es6mr14447757qab.2.1323216395590;
        Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:06:35 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <notifications@domain.com>
Received: from mail.domain.com (domain.com. [n.n.n.n])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id b16si7471407qcv.131.2011.12.06.16.06.35;
        Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:06:35 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of notifications@domain.com designates n.n.n.n as permitted sender) client-ip=n.n.n.n;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of notifications@domain.com designates n.n.n.n as permitted sender) smtp.mail=notifications@domain.com
Received: by mail.domain.com (Postfix, from userid 5001)
  id 26ADE381E3; Tue,  6 Dec 2011 19:06:35 -0500 (EST)
Received: from domain.com (domain.com [127.0.0.1])
  by mail.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0148638030
  for <person.name@gmail.com>; Tue,  6 Dec 2011 19:06:31 -0500 (EST)
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 19:06:31 -0500
From: DomainApp <notifications@domain.com>
Reply-To: notifications@domain.com
To: person.name@gmail.com
Message-ID: <4edeae07e069c_7cc1413de46597b2@domain.com>
Subject: Roman Snitko says hi
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-No-Spam: True
Precedence: bulk
List-Unsubscribe: notifications@domain.com
```

Messages go to Spam folder on various gmail accounts, so it's not a coincidence.

I followed all gmail guides on sending bulk emails from here https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126.
I also checked my ip-address here http://www.dnsblcheck.co.uk/ and it's NOT on the blacklists.

Thus I have two questions:

1. What may be the possible reason for the messages to go to Spam folder?
2. Is there any way to contact Google and ask them what causes this?

**Update:** I have set up openDKIM on my server, everything works, gmail message headers say that `dkim=pass`, which means everything is set up correctly. Messages still end up in Spam folder.

Comment: The included headers suggest your email is not signed. One suggestion that seems to make a big difference is to implement DKIM signing. Use OpenDKIM (or DKIMproxy) with Postfix. It does add a bit of overhead, but should improve your delivery rate.

Comment: This can be based on the content of the e-mail, too.

Comment: same problem here http://serverfault.com/questions/545189/email-delivery-to-gmail-breaks-after-implementing-domainkey

Answer (score 0):

If you follow that google.com support link all the way to the end, there should be a form to contact the postmaster.  However, if you *just* set up the DKIM infrastructure, it may take "a while" for the messages to not be spam:

> Were your records incomplete? Yes, my records were incomplete, and
>   I've corrected them
>
> We're glad that you've identified and corrected the problem. Please
>   note that it may take some time for your domain's reputation to be
>   restored, and you may have trouble delivering mail to Gmail users for
>   a short period of time. This problem will resolve itself as you
>   continue to follow the practices outlined in our Bulk Senders Guide.